# Emacs org mode: How to make agenda views of blocked parent tasks?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

During my daily work I want to prevent parent tasks to be visible in my daily agenda views. This is very practical during daily work, since a parent task cannot be "done", only be a placeholder for its sibling tasks. However, during my GTD weekly review of my tasks I would like to have a separate agende view showing all parent tasks, to be able to get an overview of their sibling tasks and their status.

I use the following code to make task dependencies possible and to prevent showing parent tasks.

```
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
```

If I use the code above, how can I make an agenda view that show only my parent tasks? What is lacking in the agenda view code below?

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
        ("p" "parent tasks" tags < ...missing code... > (
        (org-agenda-overriding-header "Parent tasks")
           ))))
```

Or what changes do I have to make in my code to be able to BOTH not showing parent tasks in some views, AND to show them in other views?

I do not want to manually tag the parent views with "PROJECT", since this is extra work that can easily be forgotten, and thereby clutter my daily and weekly agenda views.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1):

If parent tasks are exactly those that are blocked, then you can define a `org-agenda-skip-function` to omit anything that isn't blocked.  You can use the  options block  to temporarily change variables related to blocking (for example `org-enforce-todo-checkbox-dependencies`) to things aren't block spuriously.

Skip functions will be called with the point at each heading the agenda checks and are expected to return either `nil` (when the entry should **not** be skipped) or the location of the next heading the agenda should check (often the next entry, but you could skip entire subtrees here).

Here's a function that just checks each entry for blocking with `org-entry-blocked-p`:

```el
(defun org-agenda-skip-if-not-blocked ()
  (let ((next-headline (save-excursion
                         (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max)))))
    (if (not (org-entry-blocked-p)) next-headline)))

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("B" "Blocked entries" alltodo ""
               ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-if-not-blocked))
                (org-enforce-todo-checkbox-dependencies nil))
               ))
```

If there is some more complex rule for identifying parent tasks, then take a look at `org-stuck-projects`.

Comment: Hi erikstokes, and thansk for your ansver. I am afraid the parent tasks are NOT the only ones to be blocked, because I am using the following two lines: 

`(setq org-enforce-todo-checkbox-dependencies t)
(setq org-track-ordered-property-with-tag t)`

If I have understood this right, the first code line is blocking a task from being switched to "DONE" if not all its checkboxes are crossed. The second code line blocs a subtask to be switched to "DONE" mode if not all its fellow subtask above it are in "DONE" modus. Hence, some of the sibling tasks under a parent task might also be blocked.

Comment: You could temporarily set them to `nil` in this template so a task is only blocked if it has undone children.

Comment: How could I temporarily set them to nil inside your code?

Comment: You can set any variables by adding `(variable value)` to the options list at the end of the template.  See the help for `org-agenda-custom-functions`.  Only `org-enforce-checkbox-depencies` is relevant here.  `org-track-ordered-property-with-tag` doesn't change the blocking behaviour.

Comment: Erikstokes: Sorry for my delayed response, but for some reason the code does not sort out any blocked tasks (partent -tasks). I am testing to see if I have done some thing obviously wrong..